# COM port won't write after reading

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm new to C++ and new to COM ports, and I've spent several days trying to understand [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx), which is pages and pages of stuff that's over my head.  I just want to get a bare bones, simple example running, call and answer.

I'm trying to get a 'client' C++ application to send data over a COM port connection to a 'server', then have the 'server' reply over the same port.  This can be a blocking operation so I'm not getting into overlapped or threading or that stuff unless I need to, that stuff is even more over my head.  But this snippet is part of what I have so far in the 'server':

```
UInt8 InputBuffer[2000];
UInt8 value = 130;
UInt8 * intBuffer = &value;
DWORD BytesRead, BytesWritten;

cout << "Trying to read in listen mode" << endl;
ReadFile(SerialHandle, InputBuffer, 1, &BytesRead, NULL);
cout << "Read " << BytesRead << " bytes; will try to write back" << endl;
if (!WriteFile(SerialHandle, intBuffer, 1, &BytesWritten, NULL)) {
    cout << "Error writing this content." << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Wrote back " << BytesWritten << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << "With error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

Here is the serial port handle setup ("COM6" here, "COM7" in the other application using virtual COM ports):

```
SerialHandle = CreateFile(
    L"COM6",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);
```

And the DCB setup is the same for both applications as well so Baud rates, etc should match.

I'm stuck because I thought the SerialHandle was set up correctly.  The `ReadFile(...)` works and the following `cout` prints exactly what I expect.  However, the `if ... else` following the `WriteFile` attempt reports that it wrote back 0 bytes with 0 errors.

Why does it read, but not write?  Sorry if I'm missing something elementary but I've spent days trying to get this simple thing working and losing my mind now.  I got a working version going in C# as a sanity check but can't get it to work in C++ for the life of me.

Comment: Done a full rebuild?

Comment: `GetLastError()` may be set after `WriteFile` returns 0 bytes written.

Comment: Call GetLastError only if WriteFile fails, and call it immediately in that case, not after doing anything else. It is not meaningful after WriteFile succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

> the DCB setup is the same for both applications as well so Baud rates, etc should match

Not necessarily.  If you are using `GetCommState()`, then the application is affected by the settings already configured on the port, which might not be the same on both ports.

For this reason, I recommend not using `GetCommState()`, but setting all the parameters yourself.